# Hebrew word suggestions on ICS

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, samsung-galaxy-nexus, hebrew

I have a Galaxy Nexus with Ice Cream Sandwich OS installed, and I write emails and text messages in Hebrew and English.

The English keyboard has as-you-type word suggestions that appear (in blue) bove the keys while typing.

The Hebrew keyboard does not have that feature (it only suggest to complete contact names). How do I add word suggestions to my device?

Comment: Are you using the stock keyboard, or a 3rd-party replacement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using a 3rd-party keyboard replacement app.

I've previously used [AnySoftKeyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.menny.android.anysoftkeyboard), and can confirm that it does show word suggestions on other languages.  For Hebrew you would need to install the corresponding [language pack](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.anysoftkeyboard.languagepack.hebrew) as well.